# Why there is no method to get Resource Name from Drawable object

Tags: android

To create Drawable object from any resource we can use the following code (my image name is arrow_selected.png)

```
Drawable d =getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arow_selected);
```

But later in the application I want to get the resource name from this drawable object.
I didnot find any method to get resource name like the following

```
d.getResourceName();
```

**Why there is no such method in android API.**  **How can I get Resource Name from Drawable object?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if you really need that functionality (I'm not sure you do), you could create your own class that extends `Drawable` class and receives `Resource ID` in a parameter of the constructor.

Then you need to store this `ResID` in a special field in your class and implement `getter` and `setter` for that field. Voila!

Answer (score 32):

I was doing a search for this as well but I came up with the following solution:

```
String name = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(imageResID);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

> Why there is no such method in android API.

Because a `Drawable` does not have to be created from a resource.

> How can I get Resource Name from Drawable object?

You don't. You track it elsewhere (e.g., other data members of a class).

Comment: But If I can create a drawable from any resource there should exist a way to to store its name.