# How to convert resources into int?

Tags: java, android, resources

By doing

```
imagebutton1.getResources();
```

It returns a "Resource". How would you convert that Resource to an int? IE: R.id.xxx

I am aiming to retrieve the id of the image.

Comment: getResources() return a Resources object. Not a Resource. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

Comment: This sounds more like a situation that would involve Reflection.  I'm not sure why you'd need this.  The R.java file is created during the Build process.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611703/why-there-is-no-method-to-get-resource-name-from-drawable-object) post, your Drawable may not have an Id.

Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Would that not just give the id of the imagebutton instead of the id of the resource?

Comment: You are right. Why do you need to do that? Don't you know which resource your ImageButton has?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526585/imageview-drawable-id-in-android

Answer (score 0):

In your code, find where you assign `imagebutton1`.

You are most likely using the `Activity#findViewById()` to assign the content.

Something similar to

```
int id = R.id.imageButton;

ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById( id );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function to give you the integer resource id.

All you have to do is `R.id.(drawable name)` and that ***is*** the int.

If you wanted to get the actual integer number, you would call `getInteger(int id)`.

So in your case, just do `R.id.imageButton1`.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example to get and set image for ImageButtons.

```
    ImageButton x = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ImageButton x2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    x2.setImageDrawable(x.getDrawable());
```

Answer (score 0):

The [getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method returns the resource id from a resource name. Here's how you'd use this, assuming imageButton1 is your resource name(file name in res/drawable):

`context.getResources().getIdentifier("imageButton1", "drawable", context.getPackageName());`