# get image file name in view pager

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager

I'm displaying images from resource/drawable folder in full screen using viewpager. It's working fine  and are sliding well. now i want to save image name in sdcard,but i am not able to get image file name. if any one will please help me . I have google it, i didn't get correct solution for my expection.

code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

        //private static Context context;
        ExtendedViewPager mViewPager;
        private static Uri imageUri;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mViewPager = (ExtendedViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new TouchImageAdapter());


    }

    static class TouchImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private static int[] images = { R.drawable.nature_1, R.drawable.nature_2, R.drawable.nature_3, R.drawable.nature_4, R.drawable.nature_5 };

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                //Context context = container.getContext();
            TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(container.getContext());
            img.setImageResource(images[position]);
            img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                               int imagid=images[position];
 System.out.println("Image name " + images[position]);
 bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(v.getResources().getDrawable(imagid));// here i need to pass my resId, i can't able to pass

                                }
                        });

            //img.setScaleType(TouchImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            container.addView(img, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            return img;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Create another `String[]` with the image names and use that in `onClick` to get the name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611703/why-there-is-no-method-to-get-resource-name-from-drawable-object

Comment: First `img.setTag(position);` Then in `onClick` `int pos=v.getTag();` (maybe you have to cast). Then `fileName=fileNames[pos];` where fileNames is the array Apoorv proposed.

Comment: Even more simple as you already store the resource id: `int resid=v.getImageResource(). (Think you have to cast. Don't know if function exists).

Comment: i didn't get image name, getting only the image position as int

Comment: Is there a reason you dont show the used code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a `String[]` which contains file name and set it's itme to `img` as tag and in `onClick` get the tag. do something like this

```
 private static String[] imagesName = {"fiel1","file2",.....};
  .
  .   
 img.setImageResource(images[position]);
 img.setTag(imagesName[position]);      
 img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                           @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                            String filename = v.getTag().toString(); 
 }   
 }
```

**Edit**

If you don't want to create `String[]` then set the `images[position]` as `Tag` of img and in `onClick` get it from tag like `getResources().getResourceName((Integer)v.getTag());`

This helps me.

Comment: Without using `String[]` we can't do it

Comment: no man. you should have to assign image name to view, because `images` is Integer array so you can't get name of image.

Comment: can we try like this  `container.getResources().getResourceName(position)` but im getting error unable to find resID

Comment: you can if you know the `ResourcesID` otherwise no.

Comment: if you don't want to create `String[]` then set the `images[position]` as `Tag` of img and in `onClick` get it from tag like `getResources().getResourceName((Integer)v.getTag());`

Comment: yes its prints like this `packagename:drawable/imagename` if you get like this how you will pass to `BitMap`

Comment: need to get image name and pass into `BitMap`

Comment: Your very short simple answer does not make clear what you have in mind or problems with. Try to explain better.

Comment: @greenapps i need to get image from from Onclick and pass that image name into bitmap

Comment: You are only repeating yourself. We asked for further info.

Comment: @greenapps see my edit in `Onclick` there i need to pass my resId in `BitMap`

Comment: Well you already pass a res id. So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @greenapps yes i got it dude this line is correct i used like this `bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(v.getResources(),imagid);`

Comment: @maddy comment answer is correct it helps me. i have edited the answer