# How to get image name from Drawable Object?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, drawable, android-drawable

Somehow I have Drawable image from Drawable folder like as

```
Drawable thumb = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_name);
```

i try like this

```
String image_name =thumb.getCurrent().toString();
```

But my need image name that means image_name from thumb;

How it is possible?

Any suggestion, comment, consults; provide useful links are highly appreciate. Advance Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611703/why-there-is-no-method-to-get-resource-name-from-drawable-object

Comment: set **tag** to your `thumb` and then get it any time you need'

Comment: any example, or code please

Comment: there is no way to get it, as not only a resource, or even a file can be loaded into a Drawable. You can store in the map, which drawable holds which image, and then get it from there.

Answer (score 8):

You can try like this:

```
int imageid = getResources().getIdentifier("image_name", "drawable", getPackageName());
String imageName = getResources().getResourceName(imageid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.image_name);
Log.e("name", name);
```

or

```
String resName = getResourceNameFromClassByID(R.drawable.class, 
R.drawable.image_name);
Log.e("name", resName);

public String getResourceNameFromClassByID(Class<?> aClass, int resourceID)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Field[] drawableFields = aClass.getFields();

        for (Field f : drawableFields) {
            try {

                if (resourceID == f.getInt(null))
                    return f.getName(); // Return the name.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```