# How can I convert an int expression (from drawabale) into String expression in Android Studio (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, string, parsing, int

I want to convert my int expression obtained with this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen_image);
    imageViewFullScreen = findViewById(R.id.imageView_fullscreen);
    textViewFullScreen = findViewById(R.id.textView_fullscreen);
    try
    {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        imageId = bundle.getInt("imageId");
    }
```

into a String expression, but when I try to do it, it doesn't work.

I try to put it in a TextView, with the int expression I have the right thing, but with String I only have numbers and not text.

I want to do that to cut a part of String which interest me.

There are solution to have what I want whitout passing by a String ? or to convert correctly my int expression ?

I've try to do this :

```
imageViewFullScreen.setImageResource(imageId);
        textViewFullScreen.setText("");
        textViewFullScreen.append("Ref : " + imageId);
```

I want to have : `res/drawable/cata_01jpg`, but I have : `2131099745`

thank's for all !

Comment: visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897639/how-to-get-image-name-from-drawable-object

Answer (score 0):

The number you have is a resource identifier. You can use the Resources class to find information about the resource it refers to. This class has several methods, I don't know which one is most useful for you but [getResourceEntryName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getResourceEntryName(int)) sounds like a close match.

```
String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(imageId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function that returns the path with the name of the resource:

```
    String path = getPath(R.drawable.icon);
    public String getPath(int id) {
    return Uri.parse("res/drawable/" + getResources().getResourceEntryName(id)).toString();
}
```